# List with NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, list, nullpointerexception

I have a problem with this part of the code. It seems that if I try to add something to a list of `Client` I get a `NullPointerException`. I really don't know why because if I debug this part of the code the variable of type `Client` has information. If someone can help me I would be grateful. Here is the part of the code where the exception appears:

```
public class Customers {
    private ArrayList<Client> listaClienti;
    public Customers()
    {
    }
    public void addClient(Client c,int i)
    {
        listaClienti.add(i, c);
    }
    public void deleteClient(Client c)
    {
        listaClienti.remove(c);
    }
    public Client getClient(int id)
    {
        return listaClienti.get(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not instantiating your list:

```
private ArrayList<Client> listaClienti = new ArrayList<>();
```

You may also instantiate inside your class constructor if you wish:

```
public Customers() {
    listaClienti = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a NullPointerException because you didn't initialize your list

```
private List<Client> listaClienti = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to insatantiate your array

```
ArrayList<Client> listaClienti = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
 public Customers()
  {
    listaClienti = new ArrayList<Client>();
 }
```